# bucket all the columns in an spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to write each column of a dataframe into a file or folder, like bucketing, except, on all the columns. Is it possible to do this without writing a loop to do this?  I suppose I can also stack the columns and write with a bucketby, are these the only way?

This question is related to another question about spark Column-wise processing here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking you can use multiprocessing if to perform the operation parallelly

```
import pyspark
import sys
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
data = [
   ("var1", "a","c"),
   ("var2", "b","d"),
   ("var3", "b","a"),
   ("var4", "d","c")
    ]
    
schema = StructType([
StructField('name', StringType(),True), \
StructField('numerator', StringType(),True), \
StructField('denonminator', StringType(),True)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
"""Change how may threads to run """ 
pool = ThreadPool(3)
def parallelwrite(x):
    try:
        df.select(x).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save("/hdfsData/bdipoc/poc/inbound/{}/".format(x))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

pool.map( parallelwrite,df.columns)
```

Comment: I can give this a try, this was also what I was thinking, too